# Is there a graph neural network algorithm that can deal with a different number of input and output nodes?

Tags: neural-networks, reference-request, graph-neural-networks, model-request, algorithm-request

I am new to graph neural networks and their applications. I have an input graph $G = \{V, E\}$ and an output graph $G' = \{V', E'\}$ where the number of nodes $V$ and $V'$ are different. I am trying to learn the function where $f(G) = G'$ and $V > V'$, thus, the function is mapping many-to-one ($n$ number of nodes map to one). The Graph Convolution Network (GCN) seems to have the same number of nodes in input and output with the function being learnt. Could I utilize the GCN for my task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you look into [link prediction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_prediction). I have had good luck with the [StellarGraph](https://www.stellargraph.io/) library. They have [several algorithms implemented](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/demos/), including [GCN](https://stellargraph.readthedocs.io/en/stable/demos/link-prediction/gcn-link-prediction.html).

Link prediction is a binary classification problem. Given two nodes, $v_i$ and $v_j$, does there exist a link between them? Using a library like StellarGraph will also produce node embeddings while performing link prediction.

For you scenario I'm picturing a three step process:

1. Link prediction and node embeddings on $G$.
2. Link prediction and node embeddings on $G'$.
3. Link prediction reusing existing embeddings where each link is between the two graphs. So each link is a tuple of the form: $(v_i, v_j')$ where $v_i \in V$ and $v_j' \in V'$. If there were no links predicted from $v_i$ to $v_j'$ then that might suggest to remove $v_j'$.

In the link prediction tasks that I've outlined, you can use GCN with StellarGraph. So there should be no problems in terms of the number of nodes.

Comment: Thanks. So in case, where none of the edges exist, the node is removed? Also wouldnt that lead to lot of computation if the `V'` is much smaller than `V`.